# What happens when a running SQL query is interrupted due to Network Connectivity

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlyog

Recently, I was doing a data transfer from one table to another in MySql through the Stored Procs.
The size of the **Source table** is quite large, it has almost 50k+ rows.
And my Stored Proc has a lot of JOIN statements. So to fetch what I need, it was taking a lot of time.

Now suddenly my internet went off due to some network issues. MySql showed me a Connection Error. When the connection came back I checked my **Destination table** , at that time it was empty as usual.
But after few hours when I checked the **Destination table**, it was filled with my desired results. Let me tell you after the connection issue I did not run the Stored Proc again, but still it is filled.

So right now I'm a bit confused about what happened actually. Can anyone clarify it to me please?

Comment: TCP protocol can not reliably detect disconnections immediately when they occur unless there is intensive data transfer in progress. Since you were just waiting in an interactive session for the stored proc to finish - your disconnection might have been detected some time after the moment YOU lost connection. Normally when MySQL (or most other databases) detects that a session has been interrupted - it will stop the currently executing SQL statement and rollback the current transaction.